# Python : What is the purpose of a colon in an if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have this piece of python code below.

```
def m(list):
    v = list[0]
    for e in list:
      if v < e: v = e
    return v
 
values = [[3, 4, 5, 1], [33, 6, 1, 2]]
 
for row in values: 
    print(m(row), end = " ")
```

The result is 5, 33.

Can somebody explain me that following if statement `if v < e: v = e`?

Comment: if v is 5 and e is 3 - nothing happens. if v is 1 and e is 3 - than v is set to 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if v < e: v = e
```

can be read: "If v is less than e, make v the value of e."

As above you should put a new line to make it read easier:

```
if v < e:
    v = e
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [8]: v = 1
In [9]: e = 2
In [10]: if v < e: v = e
In [11]: v
Out[11]: 2
In [12]: e
Out[12]: 2
```

is same as:

```
In [13]: v = 1
In [14]: e = 2
In [15]: if v < e:  # if True execute next statement 
   ....:     v = e
   ....:     
In [16]: v
Out[16]: 2
In [17]: e
Out[17]: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called a colon in english, not a double colon or double comma.

I urge you to read a basic Python introduction.

```
if v < e: v = e
```

Is the same as:

```
if v < e:
    v = e
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to write that code is like this, just for learning purposes:

```
    def max_nest_list(lst):
        max_numbers = []
        for sub_list in lst:
            max_num = sub_list[0]
            for num in sub_list[1:]:
                if num > max_num:
                     max_num = num
            max_numbers.append(max_num)
        return max_numbers

    values = [[3, 4, 5, 1], [33, 6, 1, 2]]
    for item in max_nest_list(values):
        print(item, end = " ")

    #Output
    5 33
```

Or even more concise:

```
    def max_nest_list2(lst):
        return [max(i) for i in lst]

    values = [[3, 4, 5, 1], [33, 6, 1, 2]]
    for item in max_nest_list(values):
        print(item, end = " ")
```

Comment: But yeah as others said, your code is right, it's just not as readable if you don't space the conditional if statement with the execution part.