# python if statement shows errors

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please help me I am not able to find why is my python code showing errors

```
if (temp == "")
```

error is :

```
if (temp == "")
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : What is the purpose of a colon in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833625/python-what-is-the-purpose-of-a-colon-in-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `:`. Change it to `if temp == "":`