# invalid syntax when defining a function that calculates random values

Tags: python, function

I am attempting the following question from QuantEcon (https://python.quantecon.org/functions.html):

> .... write a function that returns one realization of the following random device
>
> Flip an unbiased coin 10 times.
> If a head occurs k or more times consecutively within this sequence at least once, pay one dollar.
> If not, pay nothing.

My code is as follows:

```
from numpy.random import uniform

def coinpay(k):
    count=0
    for i in range(11):
        U=uniform(0,1)
        if U<0.5:
            count=count+1
            if count>=k:
                return(1)
            elif count<k and i==10
                return(0)
```

It seems to be throwing up an error for invalid syntax. I'm not sure why that is so. The error is on the second last line.

```
runfile('/Users/xyz/Desktop/Factorial', wdir='/Users/xyz/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/xyz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-7-b7c496572ff1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/xyz/Desktop/Factorial', wdir='/Users/xyz/Desktop')

  File "/Users/xyz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/xyz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/xyz/Desktop/Factorial", line 18
    elif count<k and i==10
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Well, it should point you at the line with the error... In particular, else statement cannot stand aligned on its own

Comment: By the way, `import random`. You don't need numpy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833625/python-what-is-the-purpose-of-a-colon-in-an-if-statement

Comment: Whenever you get a syntax error, feel free to look at the official python documentation for the proper syntax until you have remembered it... 9/10 times you'll easily spot it. Best of luck

Comment: error is pretty clear out there. Just put `:` at the end of elif statement

Comment: `return` is not a function, so `return(1)` should be `return 1`. It might be a good idea to read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 2):

There is no `else if` in python, replace it with `elif` and reindent your code. Moreover, you want to use `and`, not `&`. Next time, include the tracelog please :)

Comment: Included the changes.

Comment: You still didn't include the tracelog and you didn't reindent your code.

Comment: You are missing a `:` at the end of your `elif` evaluation

Answer (score 0):

Proper syntax in your code is

```
def coinpay(k):
    count=0
    for i in range(11):
        U = uniform(0,1)
        if U < 0.5 :
            count=count+1
            if count>=k:
                return 1
            elif count<k and i==10:
                return 0
```